# Call jQuery function within function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery function (stripped down just for this example):

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.Lightbox = function(options) {

       var opts = $.extend(defaults, options);

        function initialize() {
            $('#lightbox').show();
            return false;
        };

        function close() {
            $('#lightbox').hide();
        };

        return this.click(initialize);
    };

})(jQuery);
```

I then use....

```
$('a.image').Lightbox();
```

to run it. I want to be able to call the close() function seperately e.g.

```
$.Lightbox.close();
```

How can I achieve this within my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a method for that, like this:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.Lightbox = function(options) {
       var opts = $.extend(defaults, options);

        function initialize() {
            $('#lightbox').show();
            return false;
        };

        function close() {
            $('#lightbox').hide();
        };
        return this.click(initialize);
    };    
    $.Lightbox = {
        close: function() {
            $('#lightbox').hide();
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any way I can get it to call the original close() function without repeating the code?

Comment: @fire - I'd do the reverse, tying that one to the main: `function close() { $.Lightbox.close(); } `...since there's nothing instance dependent on there, might as well keep it simple.